# Auto-format: wrapping later in line when inserting text

Tags: formatting, wrapping

After reading `help textwith` and `help fo-table`, I expected that when I set

```
set textwidth=20  " for demonstration
set formatoptions=tcq
```

then inserting text would always eventually cause a line to wrap, but that isn't the case. Wrapping only happens at (or before) my cursor. And if I paste, wrapping doesn't happen at all.

Example (Vim 7.4):

```
12345678901234567890
This is a long line
```

The line will auto-wrap if I hit `A` and start typing.

But if I hit `02wi` and type "still ", it doesn't wrap:

```
12345678901234567890
This is still a long line
```

I have to type another 7 characters before it will wrap, and then the problem continues on the next line:

```
12345678901234567890
This is still more <-- it wraps here
typing and again a long line
```

Pasting doesn't trigger a wrap either:

```
12345678901234567890
This is a long line This text is pasted and not wrapped
```

I think what I want is `set fo+=a` but that applies at the paragraph level, whereas I don't want auto-formatting of one line to spread to other lines.

Or am I missing an option?

To be clear, after launching `vim -u NONE`, this is what I type (less comments):

```
:set textwidth=20<CR>
:set formatoptions=tcq<CR>
iThis is a long line<ESC>
02wistill <ESC>                " no wrap happens, but I'd like it to
u
:let @r = "This text is pasted and not wrapped"<CR>
$"rp                           " no wrap happens, but I'd like it to
```

Comment: This seems to work fine for me. I started Vim with `vim -u NONE` to prevent loading a vimrc file. Does this fix the problem for you? Which Vim version are you using?

Comment: No, that doesn't help. Vim 7.4 on Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: Is `paste` set, accidentally? Try`:set paste?`

Comment: @VolkerSiegel no, `paste` is not set. When `paste` is set no wrapping happens at all.

Answer (score 2):

I came across a partial solution, using `formatoptions=tcqaw`. Basically, you still auto-wrap paragraphs, but a paragraph ends when the line has no trailing whitespace, which is suitable for many cases.

Using your example (with a slight modification, no undo and using "`<SPACE>`This...") I get this result:

```
This is still a long  
This is pasted and 
not wrapped
line
```